Constructing Asymptotic Interval for Mean
My question is as follows:
$X_1, ..., X_n$ are iid. realizations of random variable $X \in (0, \infty)$ with $E(X) = \mu$ and $V(X)=\mu +\theta \mu$. I am trying to construct an asymptotic size $\alpha$ interval for $\mu$. I have that
$\sqrt{n\mu(\theta+1)}(\bar{X}_n - \mu)$ converges in distribution to $N(0,1)$ as $n\to\infty$ by CLT, and I have started to construct the interval with
$P(-z\frac{\alpha}{2} \leq \sqrt{n\mu(\theta+1)}(\bar{X}_n - \mu)\leq z{\frac{\alpha}{2}}) \approx 1-\alpha$
However, I am not sure where to proceed here as $\theta$ is unknown, so it would come up in the endpoints of the interval if I were to isolate $\mu$. What are you supposed to do in this case? Use MLE/other estimate and prove that it will converge to $\theta$ asymptotically? Thanks!
